# Smart pointers still refers to raw pointer even though reset is applied

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, smart-pointers

Please find the code attached which I took from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/auto_ptr-unique_ptr-shared_ptr-weak_ptr-2/ for testing the smart pointers.

```
// C++ program to demonstrate shared_ptr
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "A::show()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> p1(new A);
    std::cout << p1.get() << std::endl;
    p1->show();
    std::shared_ptr<A> p2(p1);
    p2->show();
    std::cout << p1.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2.get() << std::endl;

    // Returns the number of shared_ptr objects
    // referring to the same managed object.
    std::cout << p1.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2.use_count() << std::endl;

    // Relinquishes ownership of p1 on the object
    // and pointer becomes NULL
    p1.reset();
    std::cout << p1.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2.get() << std::endl;
    p1->show();
    p2->show();
    std::cout << p1.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << p2.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

p1 is reset and no pointer is assigned to it (Found as per p1.get()). After that, When I am calling p1->show() function, it shows the output as A::show(). How it is possible? is it a same case on raw pointers as well?

```
output:
0x24dc5ef1790
A::show()
A::show()
0x24dc5ef1790
0x24dc5ef1790
2
2
0
1
0x24dc5ef1790
A::show() 
A::show()
0
1
0x24dc5ef1790
```

Comment: Try compiling with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then run your program. It's a very good combination of options to catch mistakes, like the one you've done in your code. It often manages to point at the exact violation/mistake done, like here: `p1->show()` - `member call on null pointer` - which means your program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works because you are not using any member from the object otherwise it would segfault. But a sanitizer catches this very easily:

```bash
$ g++ -ggdb -O0 -fsanitize=undefined,address shared.cpp -o shared
$ ./shared
0x602000000010
A::show()
A::show()
0x602000000010
0x602000000010
2
2
0
1
0x602000000010
shared.cpp:33:13: runtime error: member call on null pointer of type 'struct element_type'
A::show()
A::show()
0
1
0x602000000010
```

Change the code to add one member variable to print like

```cpp
class A {
public:
    void show()
    {
        std::cout << "A::show() " << value << std::endl;
    }
    int value;
};
```

And it segfaults

```bash
$ g++ -ggdb -O0 shared.cpp -o shared
$ ./shared
0x560a3dde4eb0
A::show() 0
A::show() 0
0x560a3dde4eb0
0x560a3dde4eb0
2
2
0
1
0x560a3dde4eb0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the `show()` function doesn't use any member variables, therefore it doesn't need `this` pointer. If we bear in mind that non-static member functions implicitly called with an additional `this` pointer, using non-static member variables in `show()` will require a `this` pointer. So it is obvious that if you use member variables in show, your example can crash, because the `this` pointer passed in will be `nullptr` in the case of calling resetted pointer.

Non-static member functions are called like this:

```
A::show(A* this)
```

Say that `A` has a member variable called `id`, and we print it in `show()`

```
A a;
a.show();
```

This converts to:

```
A::show(A*this)
{
  std::cout << "Id: " << this->id << " A::show()" << std::endl;
}
```

It enables an oppurtunity like calling the `show()` with `nullptr`:

```
std::invoke(&A::show, (A*)nullptr);
```

Unless you use nulled `this` pointer here, probably this won't crash.

But you shouldn't rely on that. It is undefined behaviour.
Never dereference a `nullptr`, just like **@Ted Lyngmo** said.

Comment: _"So it is obvious that if you use member variables in show, your example will crash"_ - No it's not. Read the other answers.

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, the problem arises a bit earlier. `p1`, which is a `nullptr`, is dereferenced, so whatever the member variables there are will not matter. Dereferencing `nullptr` is enough.

Comment: I don't think we are dereferencing a `nullptr` here. Because we really do not try to read the memory held by `p1`. We do not use pointer artichmetics on `nullptr`, we do not access it. We just implicitly post the value `0` as an argument to a function that compiler already knows. So what do you think that can cause undefined behaviour?

Comment: auto ptr = (A*)nullptr;
ptr->show();
Is this undefined behaviour if we do not ever use `this` pointer in show?

Comment: `p1.reset();` ...`p1->show();` - This is pretty much the definition of dereferencing a `nullptr`. It'd be clearer with `something *ptr = nullptr;` and `ptr->show();` but the effect is the same.

Comment: Isn't `->` just a shorthand for `std::invoke(&A::show, (A*)nullptr);`

Comment: No, `operator->` is, for a class such as a smart pointer or an iterator class, often just letting the held pointer out.  Not that it'd matter much. Invoking `show` via `std::invoke` isn't more than a smoke screen when the instance is `nullptr`.

Comment: I used the word 'shorthand' wrongly there. I actually meant something like 'it does the exact same thing'. But okay, i will think on that. Thank you for discussion.

Comment: You too! It's dereferencing the `nullptr` that matters. If you do it via a proxy or not doesn't matter.